# Performance penalties for private NS verses one from hosting company on VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, nameserver

I am planning on getting a VPS account.

Is there a performance penalty if I set up my own name server (ns) and use that for all my domains rather than use the name server provided by the hosting company?

The VPS hosting company might charge for use of their NS records above the first, which is what triggered this question, but I was also wondering that if I do use my own, if there would be a penalty.

I would be using Plesk in a Windows Server 2012 environment.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proceed no further until you have purchased [the cricket book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) and read chapters 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, and 17.

This is required reading if you intend to run your own DNS server.

---

There should be no measurable performance impact hosting domains on your own DNS server*s* versus ones provided by your ISP/hosting company, provided your server*s* are configured correctly.

You will generally need at least two DNS server*s*, preferably in geographically and topologically distinct locations. (The reasons for this are explained in detail in the book I linked to above.)

Comment: I will look into the book. I sort of know the procedure, which is to take register ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com with the domain registrar for domain.com, each with its own IP address. Then set the A record for each in Plesk under the domain.com DNS settings. After that, one would edit the DNS Template (under Server Settings) to set the NS values, however these steps do not handle the two separate server requirements. Yes, now that you mention that, I did hear that before. That means that since I have one server, that I cannot do my own name server and still follow protocol?

Comment: Also, would the steps outlined in my comment above be setting up my own DNS?

Comment: Yes, the steps you're outlining are setting up and running your own DNS server. The questions you're asking are extremely basic - to the point where I am not comfortable answering them until you've got a better grounding in how DNS works (from the cricket book, or some other suitable reference source). "DNS 101" is too complicated to do on a simple Q&A site like Server Fault.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you. I will look into the book, should be a good reference. The dual requirement negates me being able to set up my own DNS, so I will need to have the ISP / web hosting company provide that functionality. That is part of the hosting fee. Thanks for the assistance.